# Gradle apply plugin: com.google.gms.google-services

Tags: android, build.gradle, admob

When I'm trying to put apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of my build gradle or anywhere else inside my apps build gradle I get a error say it can't find it.

```
Error:(70, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
```

Here's my gradle code so you guy's can help me figure out where to place it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.technologx.blaze.player"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 101
        versionName "1.0 beta 1"
        //renderscript support mode is not supported for 21+ with gradle version 2.0
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
    }

}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'de.Maxr1998:track-selector-lib:1.1'

    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.0.2'

    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'

    compile('com.github.naman14:app-theme-engine:0.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: It's in the right spot. Make sure you have the lib installed

Comment: I do because I used it with another app before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you also need this in your projects gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you're using Firebase and you have created your project and created your app inside the project and set your SHA1 certificate, you just need to go to your projects settings on the firebase console and download the latest google-services.json file and put it in your app module.     If you havent created the project yet then you should have a look at this [get started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and this since your using firebase ads i see [ads tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)